# Difference in WHERE-order outputs different result. Why?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

My understanding so far was that SQL takes the WHERE conditions and optimizes the order for index usage etc. anyways - so why do these 2 produce different results? Where's my fallacy?

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM messages
        WHERE direction = 1
        AND date_done IS NULL
        AND YEAR(date_received) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND date_received != CURRENT_DATE()
) AS workday_start_count
```

Result: 0

```
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM messages
        WHERE direction = 1
        AND date_done IS NULL
        AND date_received != CURRENT_DATE()
        AND YEAR(date_received) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
) AS workday_start_count
```

Result: 17

Shouldn't both result in 17? Even assuming order matters, the first query should filter out (1) all messages not received in the current year, then the (2) messages received today, for a result of "*messages not yet done at the start of the day*".

The other query does the same thing, but first filtering out (1) messages received today, then (2) messages not received in current year.

Comment: Conditions order cannot influence. Search for a difference in some another place.

Comment: These queries are logically identical and therefore must generate identical result sets.  Something else is happening here, e.g. your underlying data is changing between executions, or one/both of these queries is not what is actually being run.

Comment: Hmm. Thinking about it, it was probably a parenthesis being in the wrong place. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Interesting puzzle.  In order to grasp at straws, lease provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`